# Good advice for coming to javascript (from Python)

Tags: javascript, python

I am coming to JavaScript, from Python.

I want to write testable, modular JS code, and want advice on tools, best practices and the like.  I know about:

- [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) (and the existence of [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/))
- Paul Irish (hi Paul!) and the [10 Things...From the jQuery Source](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) podcast
- jQuery, jQuery.ui and Themeroller
- the existence of freenode#javascript and freenode#jquery
- [Mozilla's MDC Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)

Stumbling blocks (so far):

What am I missing?  Idioms / techniques / tools welcome, particularly around arrays (which seem crippled compared to python lists... what am I missing?), namespacing, testing, and documentation (no docstrings?  what do I do instead?)

(also, are we not allowed to tag things as community wiki anymore?  I don't need the rep!)

Also, one answer per response please!

Comment: Users can no longer flag their own posts as community wiki, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183). It's a good question, you deserve the rep. :)

Answer (score 1):

For techniques check out this post about js patterns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002/what-javascript-patterns-do-you-use-most

Also, I use Aptana (an Eclipse derivative) as an IDE.  Works out pretty nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider investigating [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) which allows you to write rich internet applications using only Python.  It will generate the Javascript for you.  It's the same concept that Google's Web Toolkit allows Java developers to write rich internet apps (like Google Wave) but specifically for Python.

Comment: I am aware of Pyjamas, but it's nice to be reminded of it, not really the sort of thing I am looking for here though!

Answer (score 0):

I recently subscribed to this: http://javascriptweekly.com/ 
So far the links they send have been very very interesting.
A good one was this free book: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essentialjsdesignpatterns/